# Recursive script in Teradata

Tags: recursive-query, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table in Teradata, consisting of five main columns below:

```
Old   New   Type_of_Old    Type_of_New    Change_Dt
----------------------------------------------------
A     B         0             1            Date 1
B     C         1             1            Date 2
C     D         1             0            Date 3
D     B         0             1            Date 4
B     E         1             1            Date 5
```

I want to bind old - new values starting from the first elements whose type_of_old = 0 and cut the bound when it reaches to the last type_of_old = 1. At the end i want to have this data:

```
Fırst    Next       Change Dt
-------------------------------
A        B          Date 1
A        C          Date 2
A        D          Date 3
D        B          Date 4
D        E          Date 5
```

The problem is, Element B is next element of both A and D in different change dates. So when i use WITH RECURSIVE script it binds next elements of B, with both A end D starting elements.

So far, i wrote this script but i couldn't manage to cut the bound when it reaches to type_of_old = 1

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TEST.TABLE_A ( OLD_ELM VARCHAR(1), NEW_ELM VARCHAR(1), 
TYPE_OF_OLD BYTEINT , TYPE_OF_NEW BYTEINT, CHANGE_DT DATE)

INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE_A ('A','B',0, 1, DATE '2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE_A ('B','C',1, 1, DATE '2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE_A ('C','D',1, 0, DATE '2018-03-01');
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE_A ('D','B',0, 1, DATE '2018-04-01');
INSERT INTO TEST.TABLE_A ('B','E',1, 1, DATE '2018-05-01');

WITH RECURSIVE ELEMENT_PATH ( FIRST_ELM, NEXT_ELM, CHANGE_DT ) AS 
( SELECT OLD_ELM, NEW_ELM, CHANGE_DT
   FROM TEST.TABLE_A
  WHERE TYPE_OF_OLD = 0
    AND TYPE_OF_NEW = 1

  UNION ALL

 SELECT P.FIRST_ELM, A.NEW_ELM, A.CHANGE_DT
   FROM ELEMENT_PATH P
   JOIN TEST.TABLE_A A ON A.OLD_ELM = P.NEXT_ELM
  WHERE A.CHANGE_DT > P.CHANGE_DT) 
 SELECT * FROM ELEMENT_PATH
```

Data from this script is as follows:

```
FIRST_ELM   NEXT_ELM    CHANGE_DT
   A           B        01.01.2018
   A           C        01.02.2018
   A           D        01.03.2018
   D           B        01.04.2018
   D           E        01.05.2018
   A           B        01.04.2018 (Wrong)
   A           E        01.05.2018 (Wrong)
   A           E        01.05.2018 (Wrong)
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra condition (AND TYPE_OF_OLD <> 0) in where clause to remove the wrong records.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ELEMENT_PATH ( FIRST_ELM, NEXT_ELM, CHANGE_DT ) AS 
( SELECT OLD_ELM, NEW_ELM, CHANGE_DT
   FROM DQRC.TABLE_A
  WHERE TYPE_OF_OLD = 0
    AND TYPE_OF_NEW = 1

  UNION ALL

 SELECT P.FIRST_ELM, A.NEW_ELM, A.CHANGE_DT
   FROM ELEMENT_PATH P
   JOIN DQRC.TABLE_A A 
   ON A.OLD_ELM = P.NEXT_ELM
  WHERE A.CHANGE_DT > P.CHANGE_DT
  AND TYPE_OF_OLD <> 0) 
 SELECT * FROM ELEMENT_PATH
```

Not sure it will be useful for you now as I just looked on today.